# export table as insert statements from psql shell

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres. Is there a way from psql shell to export the table as "INSERT" statements to "test.sql" [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)
I tried using

```
\copy (SELECT * from users) TO 'test.sql'
\copy (SELECT * from users) TO 'test.sql' SQL;
```

I found a lot of answers online that use `pgdump`, Ideally, I want without it

Comment: If you don't want to generate the INSERT statement yourself, `pg_dump` is the only option.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the quick reply, In all postgres GUI there is an option to export to (csv,SQL,json...) they do not have a command for it?

Comment: Well, `psql` simply does not have that option. So you will have to use a different tool. Either `pg_dump` or any those GUI tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
   SELECT 'INSERT INTO users (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (' ||
coalesce(quote_literal(column1), 'null') || ',' ||
coalesce(quote_literal(column2), 'null') || ',' ||
coalesce(quote_literal(column3), 'null') || ',' ||
');' FROM users;
```

or here is good function in psql
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Create_INSERT_statement

and in python
https://gist.github.com/agentgt/2568047